# need to create all possible strings by joining all elements of an array with boolean operators

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an array of n elements in perl. I need to create all possible strings by joining all elements with all boolean operators  (e.g AND, OR, NOT). For example if

```
@arr = ('X', 'Y', 'Z');
```

I need to get output as below

X AND Y AND Z

X AND Y OR Z

X OR Y OR Z 
.....
....

Comment: also, why? This sounds like a very artificial problem. Homework?

Comment: Tip: Use nested loops (which loop over the operators), or recursion to list all possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want

```
for (qw( AND OR )) {
   for (qw( AND OR )) {
      ...
   }
}
```

where the number of nesting is proportional the number of elements in `@arr`. When you want an arbitrary number of nested loops, you want `NestedLoops`.

```
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops MapCar );

my $ops = [qw( AND OR )];

my $iter = NestedLoops([ ($ops) x $#arr ]);
while (my @ops = $iter->()) {
    say join ' ', MapCar { @_ } \@arr, \@ops;
}
```

You could also write that as

```
use Algorithm::Loops qw( NestedLoops );

my $ops = [qw( AND OR )];

my @loops = map { [ $_ ], $ops } @arr;
pop(@loops);

my $iter = NestedLoops(\@loops);
while (my @expr = $iter->()) {
    say join ' ', @expr;
}
```